# mschart y-axis min / max setting issue (possible glitch?) C#

Tags: c#, axis, mschart, max

I have a problem with setting the maximum and minimum values for the y-axis of my mschart. 
When setting the max or min to a value, say 10.025, the value the chart sets as max is 10.024999618530273.

```
mainChart.ChartAreas[selectedChartArea].AxisY.Maximum = GetRoundYAxisMax(newYMax, newYRange);
mainChart.ChartAreas[selectedChartArea].AxisY.Minimum = GetRoundYAxisMin(newYMin, newYRange);
```

The GetRoundYAxisMax method just returns a "round" value. Code below.

```
private float GetRoundYAxisMax(double calculatedMax, double yAxisRange)
        {
            double rangeFactor = 0;

            if (yAxisRange > 10)
                rangeFactor = 1;
            else if (yAxisRange > 1)
                rangeFactor = 4;
            else if (yAxisRange > 0.1)
                rangeFactor = 40;
            else if (yAxisRange > 0.01)
                rangeFactor = 400;
            else if (yAxisRange > 0.001)
                rangeFactor = 4000;
            else if (yAxisRange > 0.0001)
                rangeFactor = 40000;
            else
                rangeFactor = 400000;

            float returnValue = (float)(Math.Round(calculatedMax * rangeFactor, MidpointRounding.ToEven) / rangeFactor);
            return returnValue;
        }
```

The rounding code evaluates properly and returns a correctly rounded value, but when setting this value to the max or min value on the y-axis it sets a value very close to it, but not rounded.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: You can try setting the chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = with your range ?

Comment: Thanks @Quantbuff - seems to work! I just need to change the format depending on the number of decimal places required.
`mainChart.ChartAreas[selectedChartArea].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "#.###";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the axis label style to round the un-rounded values:
`mainChart.ChartAreas[selectedChartArea].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "#.###";`

Answer (score 0):

Just answering why 10.024999618530273 rather than 10.025.
Nothing on a computer is infinite in precision.  You have ( IIRC ) 80 bits to represent your number.  Part is exponent part is mantissa.  What is happening is that 10.025 is not a number that has perfect representation in that number of bits.  You dont get the whole number line, you get integral marks along it.  ( take a random 80 bit double.  That is a point on the number line.  Now, add the smallest increment to that 80 bit double that is possible.  Another  point on the line.  Now, in the "real" ( pun intended ) world, there are an infinite number of real points.  Any point on the line you try to represent on a real world number line will be represented as one of the two points that bound that point in the 80 bit world ).